# React Typescript property does not exist on type during array map

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have this component:

```
import type { NextPage } from "next";
export interface HomeInterface {
  data: object[];
  id?: string;
  body?: string;
  title?: string;
}

const Home: NextPage<HomeItnerface> = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      {data.map(({ id, title, body }) => {
        return <PostCard key={id} id={id} title={title} body={body} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

And in the map function I am getting this error on each destructured value `Property 'title' does not exist on type '{}'`. I tried to write Interface around it but I am doing it wrong. Any suggestions please?

Comment: What do the `NextPage` and `HomeInterface` types look like?

Comment: You need to show us the `NextPage` and `HomeItnerface` types

Comment: NextPage is type imported from the Next Library and I will update question now with homeinterface

Comment: You need to specify `data` shape, so TS knows that it contains `id`, `title` and `body`.

Comment: @TomaszStaszkiewicz could you show me how to do it please?

Comment: `data: { title: string; body: string; id: number }` for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TS does not know the shape of data - it is not aware about the fact, that it contains `title`, `body` and `id`, so you need to specify them in the interface. For example:

```js
export interface HomeInterface {
  data: {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    body: string;
  }[];
  id?: string;
  body?: string;
  title?: string;
}
```

Also - notice that you have a typo in

```js
const Home: NextPage<HomeItnerface> = {...}
```

It should be:

```js
const Home: NextPage<HomeInterface>
```

Comment: I ll be able to mark this answer in 4 minutes

Answer (score 1):

Try to set HomeInterface to this:

```
export interface HomeInterface {
  data: {
    id?: string;
    body?: string;
    title?: string;
  }[];
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I think that happens because that properties are optional,you need to garantie that there exists. So you need to verify your disponibility frist. You can do do data?.id || '', for example to make sure that are avaliable.